# Picasa in iPhone using GData

Tags: iphone, gdata-api, picasa

i have to implement Picasa client for iPhone. I have few queries in that regards.
Are the api deprecated now? What if I still implement them now? Where can I find good tutorial on the same. I don't know anything about implementing google data. Also I am a newbie for iPhone development. Also I came across a few pages which said that there in not enough documentation on the same. I have to implement Picasa from the scratch so plz guide me.
Thanx and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by learning general iPhone programming; there are numerous books for that, such as [Conway & Hillegass](http://bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide).

Once you are comfortable with Cocoa Touch development on the iPhone, you can use the [GData Objective-C library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) to access albums and photos on Picasa Web Albums. The library includes a sample photos application showing how to use the [Picasa Web Albums API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html) to browse, download, and upload photos and videos.

Comment: thanx, i m working on my iphone programming. but isnt there any other blog or tutorial which will explain stepwise

Comment: For the Google APIs including Picasa Web Albums, look for the links to the Overview Slides and Introduction at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/